# How to prove CRC can detect even number of isolated bit errors

Tags: networking, crc, crc32

A 1024-bit message is sent that contains 992 data bits and 32 CRC bits. CRC is com- puted using the IEEE 802 standardized, 32-degree CRC polynomial. For each of the following, explain whether the errors during message transmission will be detected by the receiver:

(a) There was a single-bit error.

(b) There were two isolated bit errors.

(c) There were 18 isolated bit errors.

(d) There were 47 isolated bit errors.

(e) There was a 24-bit long burst error.

(f) There was a 35-bit long burst error.

In the above question can anyone explain for option (c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 41-bit codeword with weight 18 (expressed as six bytes in hexadecimal) can be exclusive-ored with any message starting at any bit position, and leave the CRC-32 of that message unchanged:

```
2f 18 3b a0 70 01
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. If you don't understand what I wrote or why it answers your question, then you need to study more.